# Predator vs prey python program

Tags: python

I have to find the new values for a predator vs prey example.

This is my current code

```
# Prompting user for all the inputs
A = float(input('Rate at which prey birth exceeds natural death'))
B = float(input('Rate of predation'))
C = float(input('Rate at which predator deaths exceed births without food'))
D = float(input('predator increase in the presence of food'))
popPrey = int(input('initial prey population'))
popPred = int(input('initial predator population'))
period = int(input('number of periods'))

# Finding new values of predator and prey populations
for i in range(period):
    popPrey, popPred = popPrey*(1+A-B*popPred), popPred*(1-C+D*popPrey)
    print "There are {%.0f} predators and {%.0f} prey after time period {%f}" %(popPred,popPrey,period)
```

My problem now is that my number of periods on my answer is always 5. I need it to be like 1,2,3,4,5. Currently it looks like 
here are {20} predators and {700} prey after time period {5.000000}

There are {20} predators and {489} prey after time period {5.000000}

There are {20} predators and {341} prey after time period {5.000000}

There are {20} predators and {238} prey after time period {5.000000}

There are {20} predators and {166} prey after time period {5.000000}

Any ideas how I fix that?

Comment: Why would the output change? Where in your code you try to change it?

Answer (score 2):

You *don't change* `popPrey` as well as `popPred` and so you have *the same output* at each itteration.
Supposed amendment (no `prey`, `pred` but `popPrey`, `popPred`):

```
 for i in range(period):
   # popPrey and popPred is a function of popPrey and popPred
   popPrey, popPred = popPrey*(1+A-B*popPred), popPred*(1-C+D*popPrey)
   print "There are {%.0f} predators and {%.0f} prey after time period {%f}" %(popPred,popPrey,i);
```

Comment: Now my I get the right values of popPrey and popPred. My last problem is that There are {20} predators and {700} prey after time period {5.000000}
There are {20} predators and {489} prey after time period {5.000000}
There are {20} predators and {341} prey after time period {5.000000}
There are {20} predators and {238} prey after time period {5.000000}
There are {20} predators and {166} prey after time period {5.000000}      Is there a way that I can make it that the period is not 5 for all of them, but 1 for the first one and increases all the way to 5 for the last one.

Comment: As described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983011/predator-vs-prey this answer should be corrected